# Release in batch mode - change dependencies version to SNAPSHOTS

Tags: java, maven

From Maven Release plugin - [Prepare a Release document](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html), preparing a release goes through the following release phases:

1. Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources
2. Check that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies
3. Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you  will be prompted for the versions to use)
4. Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination of the tag
5. Run the project tests against the modified POMs to confirm everything is in working order
6. Commit the modified POMs
7. Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted for)
8. Bump the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values will also be prompted for)
9. Commit the modified POMs

My questions is:

Is there a way to execute step number 8 in batch mode for dependencies? I know how to change project version to SNAPSHOT using parameter (developmentVersion) but i have no idea how to change dependencies.

When I use

> mvn release:prepare release:perform

maven tells me that I have SNAPSHOT dependencies in my pom and I can provide release and development version for them. But is there a way to give them in batch mode?

I know about maven-versions-plugin:use-latest/next-snapshot but It dosen't work for me.

My version number flow should look like:

- 01.04.05-SNAPSHOT   (before release)
- 01.04.05            (release version)
- 01.04.06-SNAPSHOT   (after release)

Comment: 1) is the version of all the dependencies the same?
2) is the version of the dependencies the same as the artifact version?

Comment: Add 1. No. Depending on project there are from 1 to 10 different dependencies in different version
Add 2. No. There are different

Comment: You should check the [versions-maven-pugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)...

Comment: As I said: I know about maven-versions-plugin:use-latest/next-snapshot but It dosen't work for me.

Comment: Right now I using workaround:

 1. `mvn updates:use-release -Dincludes=my.packages.* versions:commit`

 2. `mvn -B -Dusername=xxx -Dpassword=xxx -DreleaseVersion=04.05.39 -DdevelopmentVersion=04.05.40-SNAPSHOT release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Dresume=false` (I'm changing versions numbers)

 3. `mvn -B versions:use-next-snapshots -DallowSnapshots=true -Dincludes=my.packages.* `


Step nr 3 dosen't work. I don't know why. Using my example from post in step 3 I want to change version from 01.04.05 to 01.04.06-SNAPSHOT (this snapshot version exists in my snapshot artifactory).

Comment: Ok. Found why step nr 3 dosent work. use-latest/next-snapshot dosen't allow to use version number like 01.02.33. To fix it you have to change it to 1.2.33, because of NumberFormatException. Funny in use-release it work :)
  Stiil, is there a way to do this using release plugin in batch mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx Hilikus for answer.

Answering my question: setting dependencies from SNAPSHOT exists only in interactive mode. There is no way to do this in batch mode using release plugin.

Solution for this is using release plugin next to versions plugin like this:

1. mvn -B updates:use-release -Dincludes=my.packages.* versions:commit
2. git commit
3. mvn -B -Dusername=xxx -Dpassword=xxx -DreleaseVersion=04.05.39 -DdevelopmentVersion=04.05.40-SNAPSHOT release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Dresume=false
4. mvn -B versions:use-next-version -DallowSnapshots=true -Dincludes=my.packages.* versions:commit
5. git commit
6. git push
7. Changing dependencies to SNAPSHOT and releasing it to snapshot artifactory is done in after commit job (Jenkins).

There will by 4 commits to git but the work will by done.
Becouse of my wrong version format (01.01.01 insted of 1.1.1 - PM dosen't allow me to change it...) I need to use use-next-version with snapshot allow set to true. In use-next-snapshot there is NumberFormatException.
Project version will by change to SNAPSHOT in using release plugin and the dependencies will by change to SNAPSHOT in after commit job.

Comment: Since maven 1.0-alpha-3, `updates:use-release` is now `versions:use-releases`

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. The difficulty comes from the fact that each of your artifacts has a different version. The release plugin works better to release artifacts that have the same lifecycle.

Now if you can make them have the same lifecycle then what you need to do is create a multimodule project and release from the root pom. The trick in this situation is that since all the modules and their dependencies have the same version, you should only specify the version in the `<parent>` section to trickle it down and in the `<dependency>` section use a version `${project.version}`. That way you can release everything together and the release plugin will not need to change the dependencies version since it is already a variable.

If the artifacts don't have the same lifecycle then another alternative is still to create a multimodule project and release in interactive mode (i.e. not from jenkins or a build server), in which case as long as all the artifacts are in the same reactor, the release plugin will query you for the version of each of the submodules.

Finally, if you cannot do an interactive release then I thought there was a way to specify the version of all submodule in the commandline by providing the artifactId and the version of each module, but I can't find that setting in the docs. I mention it in case you want to research it further

In all cases though, you will have better chances of succeeding if you configure your project as a [multi module project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)